# Using table record id as an image name

Tags: database, image

I have a table where each record has a corresponding image (say the table is `users` and the image is the profile image. I am saving the images in the file system.

I am thinking of using the table record id as the image name, rather than having a separate column in the table for the image name. That way I can find the profile image from the user id.

Is this a good/frequently used approach? Are there any drawbacks of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a good idea, because the user Id is likely a surrogate key generated by a sequence (if using Oracle) or an IDENTITY value (used by a number of database technologies).

For instance, sequences in Oracle are not guaranteed to provide the same values in different databases, since a range of values get cached. Furthermore, the order in which you enter users in different databases changes their primary key. So user Id = 3 in your Dev database might be your user, but user Id = 3 in the Production database might be me, because I created my user or registered before you did.

Instead, opt for using a unique value for each user that should be the same in each database or application environment, like username.

Let's say I register as "abc123" in Dev. My profile image gets stored as "abc123.jpg" in some folder. If I register in Production as user "abc123" the image used in Dev will work on Production as well.

Answer (score 2):

Using the id as the file name works fine for most applications.  This assumes you are processing the image (resizing, cropping) and saving every image as the same file format.  Otherwise you'll also want to store the file type in the table as well.

That said, a couple of the possible drawbacks to be aware of:

- You'll have to overwrite existing files when the user updates their avatar.  Whether this is a problem or not depends on how you are storing files.
- If you use the id as the file name, you 'leak' some information about your system

I like to have a separate 'uploads' table that tracks individual files that are uploaded by the end user.  Then I assign the id of the uploaded file as an avatar id.  You can also assign each uploaded file a hash value to use when generating URLs, so that the file can be referenced without an 'id' being shown.